# Show short name for paths with spaces in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like to echo and use `%~dp0` variable within windows batch script i am writing, but in some cases the path contains spaces that corrupted other parts in script, I tried to double quote `%~dp0` but it's still not working so i am thinking of using short names for path just like the format appeared in `dir /X` command but i need your help to get only short name for `%~dp0`.

would you please help ?

Comment: Not every file has a short name. In fact, short name generation can be disabled altogether at the file system level. This isn't an acceptable workaround. You need to figure out why your quoting of the file name isn't working.

Comment: This isn't a problem with the `%dp0` variable, sound like a problem with your script. Add your script to your question

Comment: start %~dp0zookeeper\bin\zkServer.cmd

Comment: If you really want to use the short names, then include the `~s` modifier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyphen before the `%~dp0` variable indicates that you want to remove the leading and trailing quotation marks, when the path contains spaces.

**For example:**

```
Path  : C:\Program Files\application
%dp0  : "C:\Program Files\application"
%~dp0 : C:\Program Files\application

Path  : C:\Windows\System32
%dp0  : C:\Windows\System32
%~dp0 : C:\Windows\System32
```

You force-use the quotation marks by using `"%~dp0"`

In order to use a path with quotation marks with the `start` command, you need to set a title for the window (can be blank). eg. `start %dp0` ==> `start "" %dp0`

As commented by @Cody_Gray, *not ever path does have a short name.*

Comment: start %~dp0zookeeper\bin\zkServer.cmd

This isn't working if %~dp0 has spaces

Comment: @user212051 try using `start "" "%~dp0zookeeper\bin\zkServer.cmd"`

Comment: That works ! Thanks !

Final thing , how to make such thing work ?

start %~dp0drill\bin\sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"

Comment: @user212051 `start "" "%~dp0drill\bin\sqlline.bat" -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"`

Comment: Can you provide me with the output of `echo %~dp0`?

Comment: C:\Users\user\Desktop\hello_duplicate\hello == copy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143598/discussion-between-sam-denty-and-user212051).